# Filter with "Contains" rationality with Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, contains

I have two sets of data, but they are not 100% identical.  I need to run a filter or vlookup of sorts to return information in another cell if there is an exact, or close enough match.

I am trying

```
=filter(BRANCHES!$D:$D,BRANCHES!$G:$G=G2)
```

but that only gives me the exact match.

Context:
In "Branches D:D" there is a list of regions in which the branch belong to.

"Branches G:G" also has the name of the branches, but they differ every now and again to what I have in Column G (G2 in the formula example).

An Example:

G2 could be PetsRus Hyper, but branches G:G only have PetsRus

G3 however could be CatsRus Local which matches 100% with Branches G:G's CatsRus Local

How do I adapt my formula to ensure that it looks for exact and partial matches and returns an the region associated to it?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER(BRANCHES!D:D, REGEXMATCH(BRANCHES!G:G&"", ""&G2))
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Here is the spreadsheet.  So I am trying to match Branches within the tab CP_Split_Helper.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HmoFQwhh9xXD58wFPtMOmPkj1t13Yqc_bouePoW-Wbg/edit#gid=1566630907

Comment: sheet is private